# glob.glob does not return any files in a fully qualified path?

Tags: python, pycharm, glob

Note: the similarly named question [Python glob.glob always returns empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619246/python-glob-glob-always-returns-empty-list) has different concrerns about *relative* pathname. Mine is a fully qualified path.

I am trying to list the files in a directory of the *stanford dogs* dataset:

```
$ls /data/stanforddogs/Annotation/n02097658-silky_terrier/* | wc -l
    183
```

Why is *glob* not finding these files

```
import glob
for f in glob.glob('/data/stanforddogs/Annotation/n02097658-silky_terrier/*'):
  print(f)
```

This returns no entries.   Why is that?  I am on *macOS* on *python3.8*

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `pathlib.Path('/data/stanforddogs/Annotation/n02097658-silky_terrier/').glob('*')` not work also?

Comment: @K.Cl  It turns out to be a _pycharm_ bug: I just ran in vanilla _ipython_ and it works.  Not sure whether to make an answer or just delete this question

Comment: @StephenBorsch beats me, what a weird bug. In my opinion, if you can track down better what's causing this, I think you should post as an answer. Otherwise, I think I would delete this, but IDK.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because   Problem is unrelated to the originally posted question (bug in different commercial program)

Comment: Why are you voting to close your own question? Wouldn't it be better to [edit] the question to make it about the Pycharm bug instead? I would guess that other people might still encounter the same and find this useful...

Comment: @Tomerikoo probably - i'm not sure offhand how to frame it . I will do that maybe end of day after deadline done. If you have an inspiration how to reframe sooner than that pls go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the "Evaluate expression" feature of *pycharm* : nothing is found there. Running the same code within the "Execute selection within python console" *does* work.

Comment: If you're positive this is a bug with Pycharm you can report it and link it here...